# Mirror symmetry in distances of remaining numbers of Eratosthenes-sieve

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Trying my first steps in Python I found an interesting phenomenon when I tried Eratosthenes sieve. Especially I looked for the distances between the remaining numbers.
For example, if you already have the primes [2,3,5] the remaining numbers of an E-sieve are
(1) 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 49 53 57 61 67 71 73 77 79 83 89 91 ...

- So distances have a repeating pattern 6 4 2 4 2 4 6 2
  which I want to write a bit differently 6 4 2 <- 4 -> 2 4 6 // 2
- to see the specials remove the always existing 2 on the last position
  then the other numbers have a mirror symmetry

| known primes | remaining numbers | pattern between | length of pattern |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | (1) 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 ... | <- -> // 2 | 1 |
| 2, 3 | (1) 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 ... | <- 4 -> // 2 | 2 |
| 2, 3, 5 | (1) 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 ... | 6 4 2 <- 4 -> 2 4 6 // 2 | 8 |
| 2, 3, 5, 7 | (1) 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 121 127 131 137 139 143 149 151 157 163 167 169 173 179 181 187 191 193 197 199 209 211 ... | 10 2 4 2 4 6 2 6 4 2 4 6 6 2 6 4 2 6 4 6 8 4 2 <- 4 -> 2 4 8 6 4 6 2 4 6 2 6 6 4 2 4 6 2 6 4 2 4 2 10 // 2 | 48 |

**My question for that I have yet not found answers:**

- is this a known pattern?
- is there any literature about this?
- have I made a mistake in my thoughts about this?

To understand better what I mean I wrote a piece of code
(it's here only a non-optimized example - for speed I already have a better variant)

Nevertheless: this is only a very theoretical way to compute primes,
the lists become very long - too long for any practical use.
The only thing I see is to use the lists of patterns to step to the next number - so the amount of numbers can be reduced, which has to be tested with other methods.

Maybe the ending 2 of each pattern gives a hint for prime twins. The growing maximum number in each pattern is also a hint for the growing distances between subsequent primes in regions of bigger numbers.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
compute follow-up primes
based on distances
of remaining numbers
in Eratosthenes sieve
"""

import functools as FT
import itertools as IT
import operator as OP


def show(C:str, Z:list) -> None:
    # Where we are - list the current state
    LB = 16  # linebreak after LB numbers to eas readability
    print(C)
    if len(Z):
        for u, z in enumerate(Z):
            print(f'{z:>6}', end='')
            if ((u+1) % LB) == 0:
                print()
        else:
            if ((u+1) % LB) != 0:
                print()
    else:
        print('empty')

def check_list(J:list) -> bool:
    # the interesting part here !!!
    # symmetry of distance list = here called jumper
    b = True
    # 2               <--> <> ++ 2
    #
    # 4 2             <--> < 4 > ++ 2
    #
    # 6 4 2 4 2 4 6 2 <--> 6 4 2 < 4 > 2 4 6 ++ 2
    #
    #  10  2  4  2  4  6  2  6  4  2  4  6  6  2  6  4
    #   2  6  4  6  8  4  2  4  2  4  8  6  4  6  2  4
    #   6  2  6  6  4  2  4  6  2  6  4  2  4  2 10  2 <-->
    #                          10  2  4  2  4  6  2  6  4  2  4  6  6  2  6  4
    #                           2  6  4  6  8  4  2 <4> 2  4  8  6  4  6  2  4
    #                           6  2  6  6  4  2  4  6  2  6  4  2  4  2 10 ++2
    #
    # check last element is always a 2
    b &= (J[-1] == 2)
    # check without the last element list has mirror symmetry
    h = (len(J) // 2) - 1  # here middle of list
    b &= (J[0:h] == J[-2:h:-1])
    return b

def main() -> None:
    # List of primes to be added in each round
    primes = []
    # distances of remaining numbers in E-sieve,
    # 1 means that at the start every number is still available
    jumper = [1]
    #
    # primes = [2]        jumper = [                     2]
    # primes = [2,3]      jumper = [4,                   2]
    # primes = [2,3,5]    jumper = [6,4,2,  4,   2,4,6,  2]
    # primes = [2,3,5,7]  jumper = [10,2,4, ... 4,2,10,  2]
    #
    show('current known primes', primes)
    see_more = True  # to see some additional output
    #
    while True:
        # follow-up prime is based on the first jumper number added by 1
        if see_more: show('start-up jumper list', jumper)
        if see_more: print(len(jumper), jumper[:8])
        print('\n', p := 1 + jumper[0], ' <-- next prime number \n')
        # put it on to list of primes
        primes.append(p)

        # To build next list we need to repeat the current jumper-list p times
        L = jumper * p
        if see_more: show('repeated jumpers', L)
        # product of primes == sum of jumpers ! LCM = border for repeated pattern
        P = FT.reduce(OP.mul, primes, 1)
        Q = FT.reduce(OP.add, L, 0)
        assert P == Q

        # Starting with 1 adding the jumpers will meet the following numbers
        K = [n for n in IT.accumulate(L, OP.add, initial=1) if n > 1]
        if see_more: show('this will meet on' ,K)

        # so we still have to handle the following numbers or adding steps
        N = [n*p for n in IT.accumulate(jumper, OP.add, initial=1) if n*p <= P]
        if see_more: show('need to strike out', N)

        # collecting together where we meet strikeouts
        J = []
        jj = 0
        kk = 1
        for (j, k) in zip(L, K):
            jj += j  # Remember the former jumper if we meet a strike-out
            kk += j
            if kk not in N:
                J.append(jj)
                jj = 0  # reset remembering
            else:
                J.append('x')
        # temporary part only to see what and where happens on striking out numbers
        if see_more: show('temporary jumpers', J)
        while 'x' in J:
            J.remove('x')
        #
        show('current known primes', primes)
        if see_more: show('resulting jumper list', J)
        assert check_list(J)
        jumper = J
        #
        if p >= 11: break
        # try bigger numbers - caution length of list grows rapidly
        # LEN jumper = product_over(p-1) <--> (2-1)(3-1)(5-1)(7-1)...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Some of the numbers you've left your table under "remaining numbers" are not prime, i.e. 15 and 25; this makes the some of the entries under the column "pattern between" inaccurate. Also, to clarify with your notation, any sequence of numbers, i.e. 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, you're writing as <- 4 ->, right? Can you clarify your "//" notation, as well?

Comment: If you remove multiples of primes $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_r$, then the remaining numbers are those coprime to the integer $P = p_1p_2\cdots p_r$. As $(n, P) = 1$ if and only if $(P-n, P) = 1$, this symmetry is easy.

Comment: @Mailbox -- the _"remaining numbers"_ is related to the first column, thus when only $2$ is sieved out, $15$ and $25$ are still canditates to be tested.

Comment: @berthold -- Maybe not exactly the links you're asking for, as starting point about ['wheels'](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesieve), and a special [property of primes > 3](https://youtu.be/ZMkIiFs35HQ)

Comment: for better understanding: the symbols xxx < x -> xxx should show the middle of the symmetry and // should show that the last number of each pattern 2 is written a bit more away from the other numbers of pattern so that the symmetry can be seen clear

Comment: yes - the remaining numbers are mostly not prime and have to be tested / striked out in former steps - these numbers are the still not striked out numbers of each step in Eratosthenes sieve - this fact is clear - what I meen is that while we watch each step there is this symmetry-pattern in the at this point remaining numbers - I tried this til p = 31 with some tricks and the very long list (needed 48GB) still shows the symmetry

Comment: the wheel is based almost on the primes 2,3,5 - thanks, but I found this already months ago - this is also a pattern but I wolud say block by block --- the numberphile video is also known and gives an explanation on prime-factors 2 and 3 but nothing for that interesting point/mirror-symmetry - additional I found an article of Pritchard sieve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Pritchard that explains to me the step by step producing the lists from a former step ...

Comment: @Riemann - as far as I remember from my time studying mathematics years ago: coprime meens the numbers have no common factor - at each step of Eratosthenes sieve some lower primes are already removed , so the remaining numbers can not have these as a factor; it's right might still have a common factor or are coprime or at least prime - but how does this come to the mirror symmetry - can you please explain this point - thanks

Comment: If $n$ is coprime to $P$, then so is $-n$, as this shares the same prime factors with $n$. At the same time, $n+P$ is coprime to $P$, too. Otherwise some prime $p$ divides both $n+P$ and $P$, hence it divides $n = (n+P)-P$. Thus we see that whenever $n$ and $P$ are coprime, so does $P-n$ and $P$. This indeed shows symmetry in the set of remaining integers when you remove multiples of some primes.

Comment: @Berthold see my post history on the tag of `prime-tiwns`, these patterns you see are inherent within the algebra.  I have also been at this stage (that you're in right now) in my elementary research.

Comment: @Riemann - now I got it / I can see what you mean - looks like that's the reason - thanks

Comment: @DanielDonnelly - so I#mnot alone who found this patterns :-) but as I wrote it doesn't realy help to compute primes - it's only that I haven't recognized / seen it before and looked interesting and I could not explain it to me in first moment